# Video is not playing in ios8 using AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, ios8, avplayer

Video stored in `documents` `directory` is not playing if i run app in `ios8` but works perfect if i run in `ios7`

I am downloading video in `documents` `directory` using `AFNetworking`.Here is the code.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlVideo];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
NSString *path = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[urlVideo lastPathComponent]];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                self.isDownloadingComplete = YES;
            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Video Downloading Failed");
            }];
            [operation start];
```

And i am playing that downloaded `video` using `AVPlayer`. Here is the code.

```
NSURL* playbackURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:strPath isDirectory:NO];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:[_pl currentItem]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[_pl currentItem]];


AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:playbackURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *anItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
_pl = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:anItem];
_pl.volume = 1.0;
_pl.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_pl];
layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 305, 306);
[self.contentView.layer addSublayer: layer];
[_pl play];
```

I think issue is with Documents Directory as i run the app, the document path is changing every time, but i am sending correct path every time. Here is reference: http://pinkstone.co.uk/where-is-the-documents-directory-for-the-ios-8-simulator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by following code

I just replaced

```
[self.contentView.layer addSublayer: layer];
```

with

```
[self.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

And it is working fine, but still i am not getting what is the problem with `[self.contentView.layer addSublayer: layer];`

Let me know if anyone have strong proof.

Thanks